# Invalid Token - Login issue - Explaination of what is being compared

Tags: joomla-3.3.x, login, security-token

I have 2 very similar (but obviously not identical) environments - one test and one production. I am using only the standard Login form from a menu item. Yet, I get an Invalid Token when trying to log into the test environment. The production environment has no such issue.

I spent a lot of time on this. Google is your friend and so, too, is the Joomla Forum. I tried numerous approaches and was offered a myriad of suggestions, all to no avail. I have "worked around" the problem.

Nonetheless, with this being a pervasive issue with Joomla, I wish to start investigating the underlying issues and what can be done about it (with the aim of preventing it in future).

An explanation is in order, I feel. Would someone far more knowledgeable about this kindly (and definitively) describe what action is being taken, what data is being compared, what the sources of the data are, where they are stored, etc. so corrective action can be contemplated. Some definitive process for identifying and correcting the issue, available only to administrators but available.

I understand why the tokens are used and I more or less understand how its being done but not sufficiently to figure out how to undo the problem when it occurs (as it will likely occur again).

As a final note, something like this makes a Joomla less attractive as a CMS. These kinds of situations scare off designers and developers. We don't need calls from our clients with this problem unless there is a definitive way of preventing or dealing with it. No such process seems to be available (at least nothing I could find and I would be delighted to be wrong about this!).

My thanks go out to those who step up to help with this.

Comment: Sheldon, you now have the privilege to vote in our current moderator [election](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/election?cb=1).  Please exercise your new democratic privilege.

Answer (score 2):

Ok this is not a solution but a way around the problem is to just swap browsers.

On Mac I have three browsers open when I am working on my development site (two would be enough) Just swap as the token (i believe) has a time limit and is basically just a login cookie. Then swap back later.

Comment: Interesting. When you say you have 3 browsers open, are you referring to, say, Safari, Firefox and Chrome? So you move around between them. I'll definitely have to try that although I'm not sure that didn't get me into trouble in the first place. Thank you for your response.

Comment: Yes that's right Safari, Chrome and Firefox. You can then login with each. For example I use one as just a guest (not logged in), one as registered and one as admin. Then the Tokens won't get mixed up. As far as I can see the problem happens (sometimes) when you try and log into the Joomla site with the same browser twice  - admin then registered for example. Having three browsers also means you can have other accounts open e.g. three twitter accounts, three google adsense accounts, etc.